# Virtual machine interaction (not management) from host command line- possible?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, xen, amazon-web-services

I have a Virtual Machine running Linux. Is there any way for me to connect to a terminal on the VM OS from the host? For instance, AWS allows you to just ssh into virtualized OSes. How could I virtualize an OS and then connect to it, say, via SSH?

My question is a little vague, because I'm not very familiar to this. **Pointers to software (Xen, vbox?) / tutorials / papers much appreciated**

Edit: say it was Linux for guest and host OS.

Comment: What is your host OS?  Are you asking simply how to SSH into a Linux guest?

Comment: Ok, theoretically, say I had a Linux host and Linux guest OS.

Answer (score 1):

From a terminal on the host machine, type:

`ssh user@x.x.x.x` <-- your guest's IP

You'll be asked about a key, type:

`yes`

You'll be asked for your password.  Enter the password for the user you're logging in as.

If your guest is listening on a non-standard port, the first command differs slightly...

`ssh -p [port number] user@x.x.x.x`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VirtualBox using the defalt VBoxManage GUI, then, by default, it create a window showing the console of the machine when you start it. If you are running the VM in the background (VBoxHeadless) then you can enable the remote desktop option and connect to the VM using `rdesktop`.

If you are uisng another VM hosting program, then you'd need to check the documentation, but I suspect all will have a similar feature.

As mentioned, if the VM is running `sshd` or equivalent, then you should be able to use `ssh` to login to it from the host (or elsewhere, depending on the network connection).